# Unable to connect to a deployed container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I deployed Docker container on AWS EC2 and exposed the port 5001 to the world, however when I try to view it on `18.130.178.90:5001/users` I get `Unable to connect`.

```
5001    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

inbound port 5001 is exposed. Public IP assigned by AWS `IPv4 Public IP
18.130.178.90`

What can I try ?

[image]

**Requested screenshot:**

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-alpine
LABEL maintainer="mark.alexa@gmail.com"

RUN apk update && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev && apk add netcat-openbsd

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  users:
    build:
      context: ./users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_prod
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
    depends_on:
      - users-db

  users-db:
    build:
      context: './users/project/db'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Comment: Deployed using ECS ?

Comment: What's your `docker run` command look like?  Can you access the application from the EC2 instance's console, or by running the same container on your local desktop?

Comment: is this instance in a default subnet, in a default vpc?

Comment: @alex067  Yes it is. The VPC was assigned to it automatically by AWS. I haven't changed it.

Comment: can you try curling the url from inside the instance and seeing if you could get a response

Comment: I really find developing a Flask app easier than deploying container on AWS. Getting container to work on AWS is such a labor. Have been trying to make it work for the last week. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was determined by ssh into the deployed container. The container was using wrong certificates. I ran locally `docker-machine regenerate-certs testdriven-prod1` then it created new certs which were applied to the deployed container and now I'm able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have deployed the container using AWS ECS - EC2 options since you are trying to connect to the container, I will assume this is a security group issue for the particular connection you are trying to make with the container. I would check the security groups first. Also, make sure the physical HOST that the docker container is currently running on is mapped to the port of the containers port on 5001. So you should see the physical hosts port connected to the port of the docker container. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It could be FARGATE as well. He didn’t clear whether he is trying to ssh into the host or he is just trying to hit the public IP. It very well could be SG issue but he needs to clear first.

Comment: Yes, I'm using EC2 (I updated the post). I don't think it's a security group issue as that's where I exposed the port 5001.

Comment: Hi Mark, can you log into the ECS instance and run docker ps to make sure that the docker container is actually running? Post a screenshot here once you do. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark Hey Mark. I am wondering why this EC2 does not have ecs-agent installed on the instance since it was built with. I see the *status* portion of the docker image running is at 1 minute. Does ECS health checks keep restarting this instance when you try to connect to it? Also, what happens when you curl localhost url with the path /users in the container and on the host?

Comment: @dtshack  No don't pay attention to the fact that it says "up for about a minute" I threw away the container and created new one and then took a screenshot that's why it says that. There's no more it to than that. How do I curl localhost ? Never done it before.

Comment: The IP of the container is http://35.178.251.62:5001/users  you will see it won't connect.

Comment: @Mark to curl localhost, just use curl localhost and it shoud give you some information back

Comment: `curl localhost` outputs `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`  But I'm not trying to access localhost on port 80 anyway. I'm accessing the port 5001 so this output is meaningless at this point.

Comment: @Mark you would curl localhost:5001 or curl localhost:5000, if this gives you some information, then we know the container to host port is working. Also, what docker image are you using for this build ? Is it a custom docker image?

Comment: Good news is that `curl localhost:5001/users` is giving me the expected output. That works. I'll update the post to show my docker image.

Comment: Okay, so we know it is working correctly and can eliminate that as an issue. Can you post a screenshot of the security group that the ECS instance has attached to it? Also, I see you are using a database, is this an RDS database? If so, you will have to allow traffic to that RDS database so the application can pull the corresponding code from it. I believe port 5432 for postgre.

Comment: I updated the screenshot showing the what ports are exposed in the security group. As you can see 5001 and 5000 is enabled but I didn't account for database on port 5432 which might be what's causing the issue.

Comment: Great those look accurate and I believe it may be the database not being able to be reached to send the correct content. Change the SG and let me know if this fixes it for. If it works, I happen to have helped with your issues!

Comment: I updated the security group to allow port 5432 for postgres and updated the screenshot. Rebooted the instance for changes to take effect but still getting "Unable to connect". This is crazy.

Comment: Make sure the Database SG is allowing that traffic as well and that should be it